# How to Activate AppCheck on React Native in Debug

Tags: react-native, firebase-app-check

I am following the documentation https://rnfirebase.io/app-check/usage to use appcheck on React Native.

When I am testing in on my Emmulator, It is not responding to the realtime database requests.

All the requests are showing as unverified requests in firebase appcheck console.

When I went through the documentation : https://rnfirebase.io/app-check/usage#activate

It is written that :

> On Android, App Check is not activated until you call the activate method. The provider is not configurable here either but if your app is "debuggable", then the Debug app check provider will be installed, otherwise the SafetyNet provider will be installed.

But process not given, how to activate ?

can some one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`activate` api is documented here https://rnfirebase.io/reference/app-check#activate

You can check a sample implementation in their [e2e test script](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/main/packages/app-check/e2e/appcheck.e2e.js).

```js
try {
  await firebase.appCheck().activate();
  // await firebase.appCheck().activate('ignored');
  // await firebase.appCheck().activate('ignored', false);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```